# TypeScript is not recognizing reducer, shows type as any on hover

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-redux

I am new at Typescript and we are using hooks in our react application. We have a common thunk action creator which calls one of the actions.

appSlice.ts

```
type ThunkOptions = {
    method: number,
    api_url: string,
    body: any | null
}

/**
 * Thunk Action Creator Factory
 * @param {String} name : Thunk Action Creator Name
 * @returns Thunk Action Creator
 */
export const commonAsyncThunkCreator = (name: string) =>  {
    return createAsyncThunk(name,async (options: ThunkOptions,{dispatch})=>{
        let requestHelper;
        if(options.method === REQUEST_METHOD.GET.id){
            requestHelper = makeGetRequest;
        }else if(options.method === REQUEST_METHOD.POST.id){
            requestHelper = makePostRequest;
        }
        const response = await requestHelper(options.api_url,options.body);
        if (response.status === 401) {
           return dispatch(unauthorized());
        }
        if(response && response.result){ //TODO: to check
            return  response;
        }
    });
}
interface AppReducerInitialStateType {
    isFetching: boolean,
    isLoggedIn: boolean,
    isSyncSuccess: boolean
}
let initialState : AppReducerInitialStateType = {
    isFetching:false,
    isLoggedIn:true,
    isSyncSuccess: false
}
export const appReducer = createSlice({
    name:"app",
    initialState,
    reducers:{
        unauthorized:(state)=>{
            state.isLoggedIn = false;
            state.isSyncSuccess = false;
        },
        //other reducers
    }
});
export const sync = commonAsyncThunkCreator('app/sync'); //a reducer function that i have not provided here but it sets isSyncSuccess flag
export default appReducer.reducer;
export const { unauthorized } = appReducer.actions;
```

[image]

`commonAsyncThunkCreator` is used in my other reducers also.

In my component files when I access appReducer, it is not recognized.
[image]
Note: Please ignore name of key accessed, I have omitted it here in my code snippet

Please tell me where I'm wrong or what approach should I take here

**Update:** I tried following steps of this post https://blog.logrocket.com/using-typescript-with-redux-toolkit/ but that didn't help either.

Also, I have found that if I do not export `unauthorised` in `appReducer.actions`, my appReducer gets recognized as a type but my code breaks since `commonAsyncThunkCreator` can't work anymore

Answer (score 1):

Since my issue was being caused due to call to unauthorized reducer, I have removed its dependency completely.

```
export const commonAsyncThunkCreator = (name: string) =>  {
return createAsyncThunk(name,async (options: ThunkOptions,
{rejectWithValue})=>{
        let requestHelper;
        if(options.method === REQUEST_METHOD.GET.id){
            requestHelper = makeGetRequest;
        }else if(options.method === REQUEST_METHOD.POST.id){
            requestHelper = makePostRequest;
        }
        const response = await requestHelper(options.api_url,options.body);
        if (response.status === 401) {
            return rejectWithValue('You are logged out');
        }
        if(response && response.result){ 
            return  response;
        }
    });
}
```

Next, I changed my extraReducers to builder syntax for TS handling and voila, my appReducer is now being recognized.

eg

```
builder.addCase(logout.pending,(state)=>{
        state.isFetching = true;
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure @mk1024, but what about doing something like this :

in your appSlice file you can do

```
export const appSelector = (state: RootState) => state.app
```

and then

`const { purchaseDetails } = useSelector(appSelector);`

Here is some ressource that might be helpful as well
https://blog.logrocket.com/using-typescript-with-redux-toolkit/

Here is an example :

https://github.com/Cvellle/Good-choice-app/blob/696baf99804611a3da27ed87b51f1770280214bd/client/src/app/store.ts ( make sure to add the correct typing in the rootstate )

https://github.com/Cvellle/Good-choice-app/blob/696baf99804611a3da27ed87b51f1770280214bd/client/src/features/login/loginSlice.ts
How to create your slice and export it

How to import and use it
https://github.com/Cvellle/Good-choice-app/blob/696baf99804611a3da27ed87b51f1770280214bd/client/src/features/header/Header.tsx#L22

Comment: this did not help. export const appSelector = (state: RootState) => state.app on hover it says Property 'app' does not exist. In my combined reducer also, it still doesn't recognize appReducer

Comment: @mk1024, I've updated with some ressources link for you to check and compare, since I am not sure about your whole code. If that doesn't help still, I'll make a little stackblitz to reproduce for you

Comment: Property 'app' does not exist on type '{ orderReducer: WritableDraft<OrderReducerInitialStateType>; appReducer: unknown; router: unknown; }'. this is what I get on export const appReduxState = (state: RootState) => state.app;. I have created store just like yours. The issue is that commonAsyncThunkCreator is using unauthorized @eren-yeager